# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in events module

Tags: node.js

Suddenly after uninstalling some dependancy packages of get-image-color, I got following error. [image]

[image]

I have included webpack.config.js and package.json files also.
webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'), filename: 
  'index.bundle.js' },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
 devServer: { contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src') },
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
         test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
         test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: ['ts-loader'],
      },
      {
         test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
         include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'styles')],
         use: [
           { loader: 'style-loader' },
           { loader: 'css-loader' },
           {
             loader: 'sass-loader',
           },
          ],
      },
      {
         test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
         use: ['file-loader'],
      },
    ],
   },

 plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
   }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
 ],
};
```

package.json

```
{
   "name": "frontend",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.tsx",
   "scripts": {
      "webpack": "webpack",
      "start": "webpack-cli serve --mode=development --env development - 
      -open --hot"
 },
"keywords": [],
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
       "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
       "@babel/node": "^7.14.2",
       "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
       "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
       "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
       "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
       "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.1",
       "@types/react": "^17.0.9",
       "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.6",
       "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
       "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
       "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
       "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
       "image-webpack-loader": "^7.0.1",
       "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
       "path": "^0.12.7",
       "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
       "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
       "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
       "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
       "webpack": "^5.38.1",
       "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
       "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
   },
   "dependencies": {
   "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
   "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
   "axios": "^0.21.1",
   "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
   "react": "^17.0.2",
   "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
   "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
   "react-router": "^5.2.0",
   "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
   "typescript": "^4.3.2"
  }
```

}

I have tried many things like target:"web" like these. but nothing was helpful. Please help me ... Thanks in advance.